# Is it possible to configure PaperTrail gem to ignore attributes globally?

Tags: paper-trail-gem

The [PaperTrail gem docs](https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail) state that you can configure individual models to [ignore some attributes](https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail#2c-choosing-attributes-to-monitor) -- This works great, but I want to skip all `updated_at` attributes (in every model). Is there a way to do this globally (in an initializer?). Something like PaperTrail.config.ignore = [:updated_at]

> Related question: [Is there a list of global configuration options for the PaperTrail gem?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41753257/is-there-a-list-of-global-configuration-options-for-the-papertrail-gem)

Comment: Can you please move your "bonus question" to a separate question? StackOverflow requires one question at a time. This question, as it stands, could be close as "too broad". Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently (January 2017) there is no global model configuration in PaperTrail. You could do this with a global constant.

```
# config/initializers/global_constants.rb
GLOBAL_PT_IGNORE = [:updated_at]

# app/models/foo.rb
has_paper_trail(ignore: GLOBAL_PT_IGNORE + [:banana])

# app/models/bar.rb
has_paper_trail(ignore: GLOBAL_PT_IGNORE + [:kiwi, :mango])
```

Comment: Thanks -- useful to be clear that there is no global model configuration (useful ref for others - Jared is [core contributor for PaperTrail gem](https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail/graphs/contributors) ).  I personally wouldn't use the constant approach for the single :updated_at but opinions would prob vary on this.