# Is there a list of global configuration options for the PaperTrail gem?

Tags: ruby, paper-trail-gem

Is there a way to find out what is [configurable in the initializer](https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail#1e-configuration) -- is it just only `version_limit` and the deprecated `track_associations`? I had a look through the the [config code](https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail/blob/master/lib/paper_trail/config.rb) and also searched for "PaperTrail.config." in the [README](https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail/blob/master/README.md].

> question originally part of [Is it possible to configure PaperTrail gem to ignore attributes globally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41548357)

Comment: There are more than two, `enabled=` and `serializer=`, for example. I'm not aware of a comprehensive list, but you could read through `lib/paper_trail.rb`. I think all the global stuff is in there. If you want to add a comprehensive list to the readme, that would be a welcome contribution.